# Google Play Service Installation

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

Q: Y SDK manager won't display google play services under extras to install the same?
   I'm using eclipse Indigo Service Release 1.
   When I open SDK manager it shows updates for SDK tools and SDK platform tools only.

Comment: Well My eclipse Indigo SDk manager does not show google play services, so I cannot install it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your SDK tools and platform tools all up to date.  Restart your SDK manager and then the updates should show up.

Answer (score 0):

**Try launching the SDK Manager by double-clicking the executable** (in my case found at C:\DownloadPath\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\SDK Manager.exe) rather than launching it from Eclipse